# GRPC, в каком потоке вызываются методы сервиса?

Tags: java, grpc

В доке не увидел ничего внятного на эту тему. Когда я реализовываю серверную часть, я могу использовать блокирующие вызовы внутри реализации сервиса, например обращение к JDBC? В Netty в рабочих потоках нельзя делать блокирующие вызовы, но в этих ли потоках работает GRPC или нет?

Где вообще можно почитать про модель потоков в GRPC, для сервера это очень важно, а в доке ни слова на эту тему.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ в API доках и исходниках. По умолчанию все потоки стартуют в CachedThreadPool. Но можно заставить их работать в потоках сервера netty, если вызвать `directExecutor()` у `ServiceBuilder`